# Split dataset without using Scikit-Learn train_test_split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to split my dataset without using the sklearn library. Below are the methods I've used.

My current code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)
```

What I tried:

```
def non_shuffling_train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2):
    i = int((1 - test_size) * X.shape[0]) + 1
    X_train, X_test = np.split(X, [i])
    y_train, y_test = np.split(y, [i])
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

However, the code above is not randomized.

Comment: what are X and y? pandas dataframe? numpy array?

Comment: It was panda frame and then this is what I did: 

data = df.to_numpy()
X = data[:, :-1] 
y = data[:, -1] - 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a shuffled order using `np.random.permutation` and then subset using `np.take`, this should work on both numpy array and pd dataframes:

```
def tt_split(X, y, test_size=0.2):

    i = int((1 - test_size) * X.shape[0]) 
    o = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
    
    X_train, X_test = np.split(np.take(X,o,axis=0), [i])
    y_train, y_test = np.split(np.take(y,o), [i])
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

Test it on numpy array:

```
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(50,10))
y = np.random.normal(0,1,(50,))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tt_split(X,y)
[X_train.shape,y_train.shape]
[(40, 10), (40,)]
```

Test it on pandas data frame:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(50,10)))
y = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0,1,50))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tt_split(X,y)
[X_train.shape,y_train.shape]
[(40, 10), (40,)]
```